# Images on WordPress with Parameters Don't Work

Tags: wordpress, apache, timthumb

Latest WP and latest TimThumb script. When I visit http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Eavis-1.jpg&w=520&h=280&zc=1 I get a 404 but when I visit http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Eavis-1.jpg it works

I can see the string starts with &w rather than ?w

Any reason why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the latest TimThumb script and it worked

Answer (score 0):

In your first link you have Eavis-1.jpg&w=.... etc. Change the & to ? like this Eavis-1.jpg?w=... and it should work:
http://www.festivalconference.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Eavis-1.jpg?w=520&h=280&zc=1

Comment: Thanks but TimThumb (I presume) creates the link itself?!?

Comment: Sorry, I have never used TimThumb before so I don't know how it creates its links, I just saw that the one you pasted was broken.

Comment: The full link is http://www.festivalconference.com/wp-content/themes/yamidoo_pro/scripts/timthumb.php?src=http://www.festivalconference.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/branding_eventbrite_1-e1374092849587.jpg&w=520&h=280&zc=1